# Maginification gesture unresponsive using ZStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to create an interface to display a set of bezier paths (vector image) which would enable the user to change the property of each bezier path (e.g. fill color) and also resize the image as a whole in order to enable the interaction with smaller paths.

For testing purpose, I have created a grid of rectangles as ZStack; I wanted to try changing the color of the rectangle upon tap and also check how responsive the user interface is, assuming that in real case there could be more than 1000 paths.

Below is the implementation code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PathView: View {
    @State var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            geometry in
            let rectangles: [GridItem] = getSquareGrid(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, count: 10)
            let rects = ZStack {
                ForEach(rectangles) { rectangle in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: rectangle.cornerRadius, style: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.continuous/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .fill(rectangle.color)
                        .frame(width: rectangle.size, height: rectangle.size)
                        .offset(x: rectangle.offsetX, y: rectangle.offsetY)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            print("rectangle \(rectangle.id) tapped")
                            // TODO: implement the logic to change the fill of the tapped shape/path
                                
                        }
                }
            }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .topLeading)
            .scaleEffect(scale)
            .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
                        .onChanged({ (scale) in
                            self.scale = scale.magnitude
                        })
                        .onEnded({ (scaleFinal) in
                            self.scale = scaleFinal
                        }))
            rects.drawingGroup()
            
        }
    }
}

struct GridItem: Identifiable {
    let size: CGFloat
    let offsetX: CGFloat
    let offsetY: CGFloat
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat
    let color: Color
    let id = UUID()
    
    init(size: CGFloat, offsetX: CGFloat, offsetY: CGFloat, cornerRadius: CGFloat, color: Color) {
        self.size = size
        self.offsetX = offsetX
        self.offsetY = offsetY
        self.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.color = color
    }
}

func getSquareGrid(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, count: Int) -> [GridItem] {
    var rectangleArray: [GridItem] = []
    let size = min(width, height)
    let rectangleSize = round(size/CGFloat(count))
    for row in 0...count - 1 {
        for column in 0...count - 1 {
            let rect = GridItem(size: rectangleSize, offsetX: CGFloat(column) * rectangleSize, offsetY: CGFloat(row) * rectangleSize, cornerRadius: 10, color: Color.red)
            
            rectangleArray.append(rect)
        }
    }
    return rectangleArray
}

struct PathView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PathView()
    }
}
```

When trying to resize the whole grid, I noticed that it is not responsive. What I wanted to ask is whether the magnification gesture has not been implemented optimally or ZStak is not a good option in case of having a large number of items placed on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add .contentShape

```
}.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .topLeading)
.contentShape(Rectangle())       // << here !!
.scaleEffect(scale)
```